# How MACROS work in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define mul(p,q) p*q
int main(){
int a=5;
printf("%d",mul(a+3,a-2));
return 0;
}
```

I expected this to print 24, but I got 18. Why is that happening?

Comment: You can run the pre-processor `cpp` and see its output to understand how it works.

Comment: It would be better to write "I expected this to print 24, but I got 18.  Why is that happening?"  The way you wrote it, it sounds like you think the compiler is malfunctioning. Arguably this *is* a design error in the language, but it can't ever be fixed, and when debugging you should always *start* with the assumption that you have made a mistake, not that you have found a bug in a library or the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically, find and replace before compiling. Your code becomes

```
int main(){
    int a=5;
    printf("%d",a+3*a-2);
    return 0;
}
```

instead of `#define mul(p,q) p*q` you should do `#define mul(p,q) ((p)*(q))`. Then your code would become as below and you would get the expected answer.

```
int main(){
    int a=5;
    printf("%d",((a+3)*(a-2)));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the preprocessor does something surprising to your code, you can find out what it was by inspecting the preprocessed output.  With a Unixy compiler, use the `-E` command-line option:

```
$ gcc -E test.c | sed -ne '/main/,$p'
int main(){
int a=5;
printf("%d",a+3*a-2);
return 0;
}
```

(The sed bit is to eliminate thousands of lines of irrelevant material produced by the inclusion of `stdio.h`.)

Macro expansion has produced

```
printf("%d",a+3*a-2);
```

Do you understand why you get a surprising answer now?

This is a very common problem people have with the C preprocessor.  The GNU CPP manual has an entire section entitled "[Operator Precedence Problems](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/cpp/Operator-Precedence-Problems.html)" discussing it.  The short version is that your macro definition should have been

```
#define mul(p,q) ((p)*(q))
```